# exclude records from select command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have a select command and it's working really well.

I want to exclude one record where SchoolID = ?

How can I do that?

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [School], [CenShort], [Center], [NameLevel],
[Tuition_Tuition] FROM [ASchools] 
WHERE (([SectID] = ?) AND (([LevelNo] = ?)
      OR ([LevelNo] = ?) OR ([LevelNo] = ?) OR ([LevelNo] = ?)
      OR ([LevelNo] = ?)) AND (([TSchools_Tuition] = ?) OR ([TSchools_Tuition] = ?) 
      OR ([TSchools_Tuition] = ?)) AND ([Gender] = ?))">
```

Comment: Just add it to your `where` clause, only `SchoolID <> ?`

Comment: Using AND. (BTW, you can do `[LevelNo] IN (?, ?, ?...` instead of all those OR's.)

Comment: Don't forget about Bobby Tables http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thank you guys your comments where helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [School], [CenShort], [Center], [NameLevel],
[Tuition_Tuition] FROM [ASchools] 
WHERE (([SectID] = ?) AND (([LevelNo] = ?)
      OR ([LevelNo] = ?) OR ([LevelNo] = ?) OR ([LevelNo] = ?)
      OR ([LevelNo] = ?)) AND (([TSchools_Tuition] = ?) OR ([TSchools_Tuition] = ?) 
      OR ([TSchools_Tuition] = ?)) AND ([Gender] = ?) and school<>?)">
```

Comment: Thank you Madhivanan your response was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to append the additional condition to the end of your where clauses. Also use the syntax `IN (valueA,valueB,valueC)` to make your query easier to read.

```
SelectCommand=
@"SELECT [School], [CenShort], [Center], [NameLevel], [Tuition_Tuition] 
FROM [ASchools]  
WHERE [SectID] = ? 
  AND [LevelNo] in(?,?,?,?) 
  AND [TSchools_Tuition] in (?,?,?) 
  AND [Gender] = ? 
  AND [SchoolID] <> ?"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can also do:

```
WHERE ...
AND NOT SchoolID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If SchoolID is your primary search parameter, then you should reform your where clause like this: WHERE SchoolID<>? AND (...all other conditions you have).
So now your query will first exclude record/s with certain SchoolID and then proceeds further with other conditions.